# Cannot register a Feature dataset

Tags: arcgis-10.1, data, enterprise-geodatabase, features, attribute-table

I am having an issue trying to register a dataset, and being able to edit a featureclass within it.

I am new to SDE so please bear with my explanation.  I read online you cannot register a feature dataset that has a topology in it, which my feature dataset does.  So it is technically "unregistered"?  But when I am in Arcmap 10.1 it will not let me edit the feature class, most specifically the table associated with the feature, in this feature dataset, and when i open an editting session i get the warning that the layer is not versioned.

Am I missing a step that will allow me to edit this feature class within this unregistered dataset? Compressing is grayed out so I am not even able to do that.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you turn off versioned editing in the editing options dialog?  On the editor menu, click options, then look at the versioning tab.

You can also take a look at this question: [SDE Versioned Data Editing Problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65854/sde-versioned-data-editing-problem)

When you talk about a registering a dataset, you may want to say registering as versioned.  There are multiple types of registrations in the geodatabase.  The other I can think of is registered vs unregistered datasets with sde and the geodatabase.

Answer (score 2):

I don't often use topologies, but I do use geometric networks a lot. As far as I know, you **can** register the data as versioned, but you **can't** register the data as versioned with the option to move edits to base - which is asked when you first click to register the data as versioned. This option will be grayed out if any of the features participate in a topology, geometric network, etc.

All you need to do is connect to the SDE database in ArcCatalog with the same account that loaded the data - the data owner - and right click on the dataset and go to Manage ---> Register As Versioned... and then hit OK.

After this you should be able to edit the data in a multi-user environment.

[image]

**Remember** - You need to register the entire dataset as versioned - not just the feature class inside the dataset. You can't version individual feature classes inside the dataset. It's the whole dataset or none of it.

If there are tables or feature classes **outside** the dataset, you must version those individually the same way.

---

Just realized how old this post is.